# Is there a composite number for which this game with composite numbers never ends?

Tags: conjectures

I created some "game" a couple of days ago and modified it during the last hour or so and now I want to present it to you.

Choose some natural number $>1$. If the chosen natural number is of the form $p^n$, where $p \in \mathbb P$ and $n \in \mathbb N$ then the game is over.

But if the chosen number has $k \geq2$ different prime factors (abbreviated as dpf in the rest of the text) then we add to that number the next number which also has $k$ dpf. If after adding we arrive at the number of the form $p^n$ then the game is over. But if after adding we arrive at a number that has $l \geq 2$ dpf then we add to it the next number which has $l$ dpf. We continue in this way until we arrive at the number of the form $p^n$ and then the game is over.

To clarify if something is not clear, let us take as an example the number $12$. It has two dpf and the next number that has two dpf is $14$ so we arrive at $12+14=26$ which has two dpf, the next number that has two dpf is $28$ so we arrive at $26+28=54$ which has two dpf and the next one with two dpf is $55$ so we arrive at $54+55=109$ which is prime and the game is over.

> Does there exist at least one composite number for which this game is never over?

This seems (at least to me) as a very hard question and I would like to call the composite numbers for which the game never ends an *awesome numbers*, although maybe the number of those numbers equals zero, but that is yet to be proved.

Comment: Starting with $70$ and going for 188 steps gives you a $59$ digit number. There is no pattern emerging and I wouldn't be surprised if it eventually ends, but I can't see any argument for or against.

Comment: @Wojowu Is there some pattern on how the number of dpf changes (for example for the number 70)?

Comment: A lazy heuristic would be that each number is a little over twice the previous , $N$ is prime with probability $1/\ln{N)$.  Adding the reciprocals of $\ln(2^n K)$ gives a divergent series. Of course sometimes there is a bigger jump. And maybe we are biased towards adding an even number to an even number

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz Is it reasonable to expect that there can be arbitrarily large jumps and that really there are arbitrarily large jumps?

Comment: I feel that this is a nice q, I'd like it to stay here, on MO. Perhaps a more profound (less random) question would be by modifying the phrase "we add to that number the next number which also has k dpf" to "we add to that number an arbitrary larger integer which also has k dpf". I'd be interested in both versions.

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński I have few other versions of this game but I do not feel the need to post them because they are similar to this one and do not look more easily answerable. Thank you for your support.

Comment: I don't feel that the two versions are similar. They may sound similar though.

Comment: The standard notation for the number of distinct prime factors of $n$ is $\omega(n)$. Concerning the "arbitrary larger number" version, I suspect that for any $n$ with $\omega(n)=k>1$ there is a number $m$ with $m>n$, $\omega(m)=k$, and $\omega(n+m)=1$, end of game.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Why do you suspect? I cannot believe that that claim is not proven? Is it?

Comment: @Wojowu Are you sure you computed it correctly? For 70, the next non-prime-power is 72 which gives 142; for 142 it is 143, which gives 285; for 285 it is 286, which gives 571; and 571 is prime, so it stops here. Until 100, the largest chain I found was 87 $\to$ 175 $\to$ 351 $\to$ 703 $\to$ 1407 $\to$ 2815 $\to$ 5631 $\to$ 11263 $\to$ 22527 $\to$ 45055 $\to$ 90111 $\to$ 180223 $\to$ 360447 $\to$ 720895 $\to$ 1441791 $\to$ 2883583 $\to$ 5767167 $\to$ 11534335 $\to$ 23068671 $\to$ 46137343 $\to$ 92274687 $\to$ 184549375 $\to$ 369098751 $\to$ 738197503 (the latter being prime)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე 70 has three prime factors, 72 only has two.

Comment: Oh I completely missed this condition, thank you!

Comment: What kind of answer are you hoping for, except for heuristic guesses? -- The operation "add the next number with the same number of prime divisors" seems in no way natural, and figuring out whether iterating this will always eventually yield a prime power seems hopeless, I think.

Comment: @StefanKohl Hello there Stefan, it is not that I am really expecting to see soon an answer which is complete and rigorous solution because this really, as you say, seems hopeless, a question was posted because I wanted to share it with the people here on site just because there might be someone who loves questions like this one and maybe will think about methods with which we could solve it. Also, I did not want that the question stays in my room written on a paper for years or so,  so I posted it on this site.

Comment: @BehindEnemyLines if you are at $n$ the next jump is $n+1$ so yes.